# Compare 2 objects and update the matching object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare 2 array of objects and update the matching object as well as total count in the object

```
let arr1 = [{status: 'Total', count: 0, text: 'Total applications'},
{status: 'submitted', count: 0, text: 'Applications submitted'},
{status: 'Rejected', count: 0, text: 'Applications rejected'}]

let arr2 = [
   {status: "submitted", count: 20} ,
{status: "Rejected", count: 10}
]
```

function

```
 let finalResult = arr2.map(function(a){
       var result=arr1.filter(b=> a.status==b.status ?  {...a, count:b.count} : arr1[0].count:arr1[0].count  );
       return result
     
   })
```

Final Result should be like this:

```
 [{status: 'Total', count: 30, text: 'Total applications'},
{status: 'submitted', count: 20, text: 'Applications submitted'},
{status: 'Rejected', count:10, text: 'Applications rejected'}
]
```

Comment: if these status are unique, why don't you have them as object keys instead of array ?

Comment: need to return array of objects only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through second array and build a hash map and also find total value. now just loop over first array and update values accordingly

```js
let arr1 = [{status: 'Total', count: 0, text: 'Total applications'},{status: 'submitted', count: 0, text: 'Applications submitted'},{status: 'Rejected', count: 0, text: 'Applications rejected'}]

let arr2 = [{status: "submitted", count: 20} ,{status: "Rejected", count: 10}]

let total = 0;
let obj = {}

// finding total and build hash map
arr2.forEach(data => {
  obj[data.status] = obj[data.status] || data
  total += data.count
})

// loop over first array and update count accordingly
let final = arr1.map(data => {
  if(data.status === 'Total'){
    return {...data, count: total}
  } else if(data.status in obj){
    return {...data, ...obj[data.status]}
  } else {
    return data
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

First find the object with the `Total` status. Then loop over the second array of objects, find each object's index within the first array, update the count of the object, then finally update the total count.

```js
let arr1=[{status:"Total",count:0,text:"Total applications"},{status:"submitted",count:0,text:"Applications submitted"},{status:"Rejected",count:0,text:"Applications rejected"}],arr2=[{status:"submitted",count:20},{status:"Rejected",count:10}];

let total = arr1.find(obj => obj.status === 'Total');

for (const obj of arr2) {

  const { count } = obj;

  const index = arr1.findIndex(o => {
    return o.status === obj.status
  });
  
  arr1[index].count = count;

  total.count += count;

}

console.log(arr1)
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)